# Facebook signed request is page liked alternatives

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

According to the Facebook developer documentation page liked is no longer included in the signed request.

[image]

I've tried switching my method of determining wether or not the user has liked my tab by querying the Graph.

Now Facebook is refusing my user_likes approval with the following

[image]

What is my best alternative for determining wether or not the user has liked my page if both of these methods are no longer valid?

Comment: Facebook does not _want_ you to do like gating any more, Facebook does not _allow_ you to do like gating any more. And there are no alternatives, because – see first sentence.

Comment: @CBroe You are correct. I did a little more digging and found this article discussing the changes. http://www.insidefacebook.com/2014/08/12/life-after-like-gating-how-to-keep-growing-and-engaging-your-fan-base/ I have a hard time keeping up with all the changes with the little Facebook development that I do.